# Работа приложения с Windows Form в фоновом режиме

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-service

У меня есть рабочее приложение, написанное для себя, которое перемещает файлы. Для финального завершения осталось доделать, чтобы оно работало в фоновом режиме и значок находился на панели задач в левой части панели(например как Скайп).

Первое, что я нашел в инете - Windows Service, но у скайпа службы нет, а он при этом работает автоматически в фоновом режиме. Еще я нашел методы, которые просто скрывают форму и отображают ее.

Что мне необходимо использовать чтобы реализовать данную фоновую работу приложения, при условии, что фоновая работа должна запускаться и останавливаться с формы?

Comment: Скрывать и показывать форму, а для значка в области уведомлений используйте [NotifyIcon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Windows service вам не подойдет, так как сервисы не имеют доступа к оконной подсистеме винды, то есть они не могут показывать окна вообще, они только в фоне работают.